# How to use Screen Orientation on a Windows phone 7 to display text?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, screen-orientation

I'm learning how to use Supported Orientations to change values or texts in a textblock. What I want is that when the device is tilted to landscape mode, the textblock should display "Bye" and when it is tilted to portrait mode, it should say "Welcome"

I want to know what relational operators should be used inside the if() statement so that it gives the correct output.

What should I use inside `if()`?

1. `if(Orientation.Equals(SupportedOrientation.Portrait)) { // display "Welcome"}`
2. `if(SupportedOrientation.Equals(SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait)) {// display "Welcome"}`

How can I use orientation to change any values I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use either the OrientationChanged event of the PhoneApplicationPage class, or override the OnOrientationChanged method if you're writing code in your page class.

```
this.OrientationChanged += new EventHandler<OrientationChangedEventArgs>(MainPage_Orientationchanged)

void MainPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)

  {
     if (orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
     orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)

  {

    textblock.text = bye;

  }

if (orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitLeft ||
     orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitRight)

{

    textblock.text = welcome;
}

 }
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked. I have more questions though, instead of LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight, I modified the code as
if(orientation ==PageOrientation.Landscape) and I tried to execute, it didn't work! Why didn't it work? doesn't 'Landscape' include both Landscape Left and right?

Comment: the event only fires after you change the orientation to landscape left or right.If you turn left then the event check the landscape orientation happens in left or right direction as it is a default behavior of orientation controls. if you simply mention as landscape then orientation control cant find whether the movement is from right or left thats why it not works.we should do different allignments of controls for both left and right landscape orientation in case of using many ui controls in our page, so its the must for to check the left and right